# IOS Convert URL string to NSString?

Tags: ios, string, url, nsstring

I have a problem to convert an `URL string`, which I extract from XML file to `NSString`.

The `URL string` look like this, it looks like odd but it is `URL` format.

```
%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22LEFT%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE%3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%u53F0%u5317%u7E2323141%u65B0%u5E97%u6C11%u6B0A%u8DEF130%u5DF714%u865F5%u6A13%3C/FONT%3E%3C/P%3E%3C/TEXTFORMAT%3E
```

However, when I use `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding` method, it return nil.

After some experiment and research, seems this `URL` contain `%u` cause problem while converting `URL` and this `%u` looks like `unicode`, however, I try to remove all `%u` then `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding` method return a proper string without any problem.

Does anyone know how can I convert this `URLstring` to `NSString` properly?

Comment: try to use NSRegularExpression?

Comment: Indeed the %u is non-standard, and was actually rejected as a standard so it is likely the iOS does not conform to it.  You will have to translate these characters yourself.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Non-standard_implementations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is Unicode han characters in your urlString thats why it is not converting.

Replace %u to \u and you will get your String.

```
NSString *str=@"%3CTEXTFORMAT%20LEADING%3D%222%22%3E%3CP%20ALIGN%3D%22LEFT%22%3E%3CFONT%20FACE %3D%22Arial%22%20SIZE%3D%2212%22%20COLOR%3D%22%23000000%22%20LETTERSPACING%3D%220%22%20KERNING%3D%220%22%3E%u53F0%u5317%u7E2323141%u65B0%u5E97%u6C11%u6B0A%u8DEF130%u5DF714%u865F5%u6A13%3C/FONT%3E%3C/P%3E%3C/TEXTFORMAT%3E";
str=[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%u" withString:@"\\u"];
NSString *convertedStr=[str stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"converted string is %@ \n",convertedStr);
```

output :---------------

```
converted string is <TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Arial" SIZE="12" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">\u53F0\u5317\u7E2323141\u65B0\u5E97\u6C11\u6B0A\u8DEF130\u5DF714\u865F5\u6A13</FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>
```

for more Info follow this [url](http://www.charbase.com/53f0-unicode-cjk-unified-ideograph)
This is **chinese unicode char**
here is some code that will prove it:

```
NSString *newStr=@"\u53F0\u5317\u7E2323141\u65B0\u5E97\u6C11\u6B0A\u8DEF130\u5DF714\u865F5\u6A13";
NSLog(@"chinese string is %@",[newStr stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding]);
```

output:----------------------
    **台北縣23141新店民權路130巷14號5樓**

go to google translate converting this string will give you someone's address.
as :-

**Citizens Xindian, Taipei County 23141 Road 130, 5th Floor, No. 14, Lane**

Comment: May I ask how can I extract Unicode string from urlString in IOS?

Comment: your answer resides in my answer need to find it out.