# Convert percentage (i.e., %XY) code into utf-8 code with Objective C

Tags: objective-c, utf-8

I have my own private protocol handler "open://" written in Objective-C on Mac. 
The issue is that the `open://노자1강` in the web browser is changed into `open://%EB%85%B8%EC%9E%901%EA%B0%95` when it's fed into the handler, and I need to transform that into the UTF-8 character back.

How can I do the code transform with Objective-C?

Comment: Use `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that does the transformation:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *str = @"open:///%EB%85%B8%EC%9E%901%EA%B0%95/index.md";
        str=[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%u" withString:@"\\u"];
        NSString *convertedStr=[str stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"converted string is %@ \n",convertedStr);
    }
}
```

The hint is from [IOS Convert URL string to NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849271/ios-convert-url-string-to-nsstring)